# ng-init pass value by new obj

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
<body>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl2" ng-init="person = new Person('John','Doe')">

First Name: <input type="text" ng-model="person.firstName"><br>
Last Name: <input type="text" ng-model="person.lastName"><br>
<br>

Full Name: {{person.sayGreeting('1')}}       
</div>

<script>
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);



app.controller('myCtrl2', function ($scope) {
 

     function Person(fName,lName){
       this.firstName = fName;
     this.lastName = lName;
    this.sayGreeting = function(lan){
         if(lan=="1") return '1 : ' + this.firstName+' '+this.lastName;
            
         else return '2: ' + this.firstName+' '+this.lastName;
            
        }
      }
 }
  
    
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: If you post your code instead of linking a screenshot, it would be much easier to find out what your problem is.

Comment: please help me.

Answer (score 1):

This is a code with a few modifications, I hope it can help you.

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
    <body>
    
    <div ng-app="myapp" ng-controller="myCtrl2" ng-init="person = Person('John','Doe')">
    
    First Name: <input type="text" ng-model="person.firstName"><br>
    Last Name: <input type="text" ng-model="person.lastName"><br>
    <br>
    
    Full Name: <label>{{sayGreeting('1')}}</label> 
    </div>
    
    <script>
    var app = angular.module('myapp', []);
    
    
    
    app.controller('myCtrl2', function ($scope) {
     
        $scope.person={};
                
         $scope.Person= function(fName,lName){
            $scope.person.firstName = fName;
          $scope.person.lastName = lName;
                       return $scope.person;
    
       
          }
                  $scope.sayGreeting = function(lan){
             if(lan=="1") return '1 : ' +  $scope.person.firstName+' '+ $scope.person.lastName;
                
             else return '2: ' +  $scope.person.firstName+' '+ $scope.person.lastName;
                
            }
     });
      
    
    </script>
    
    </body>
    </html>
```